# Why is average calculating program showing different results after decimal points?

Tags: c

```
**While runnning the C program the output is 33.000
```

Meanwhile the correct answer is 33.200
 what is wrong is there any data return type issue with float,
 so Should I use double data type I getting i head stuck **

```
#include <stdio.h>

 float passingmarksArrray(int studentmarks[5]);

 int main(){

 float studentmarks_Average ;
 int marks[5] = {21, 24, 32, 45, 44};

 studentmarks_Average  = passingmarksArrray(marks);

printf("The average marks of the student is %.3f \n", studentmarks_Average );

 return 0;
}



 float passingmarksArrray(int studentmarks[5]){

 int i;

 int sumofmarks = 0;

 float average;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{

sumofmarks = sumofmarks + studentmarks[i];

}

average = (sumofmarks / 5) ;

return average;

}
```

Comment: Change `average = (sumofmarks / 5)` to `average = (sumofmarks / 5.0)`

Comment: Please consider marking your question as answered if it is, as it seems to be.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, the statement

```
 (sumofmarks / 5) ;
```

is an integer division, which will not yield a floating point result. To obtain a floating point result, you need to enforce floating point division, by saying

```
(sumofmarks / (float)5) ;
```

or

```
(sumofmarks / 5.0) ;
```

Comment: This is potentially misleading, since `(float) 5` is absolutely not the same as `5.0`. The correspondence would be `5.0f`, or `(double) 5`. Either way, it might also be worth pointing out that the cast should be reserved for *variables* (or expressions) — when dealing with literals, there’s no need for it and there are some people who strongly prefer writing `5.0` or `5.0f` to get the appropriate type.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I never claimed they are same, but would they both not cause the floating point division?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I didn’t claim you claimed that. I merely noted that their juxtaposition might give the misleading impression they were the same. And yes, both cause floating-point division but the result type will differ (and, when assigned to a variable, might lead to a potentially lossy truncation).

Answer (score 0):

In the expression **(average = (sumofmarks / 5))**

*sumofmarks / 5* returns an integer value which is then converted to float and stored in *average*.

while *sumofmarks / 5.0* returns float value.